# How can I link to a React webpage from a plain JavaScript webpage?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am making a portfolio website with GitHub Pages, and I want to link 3 of my projects on it, but 2 of them were created with `create react app` and so to start them I use `npm start`. How can I link to these pages on my portfolio so that they open like a webpage does when clicked?

The closest thing I could link would be App.js in the React project folder, but when I click on it, it just opens the source code in the browser. I basically want to emulate what happens when I type `npm start` in the console, but have it do that after clicking a link. Is that possible?

Comment: Check this out https://github.com/gitname/react-gh-pages

Comment: When you run `yarn build` or `npm run build` in your react projects, This command will compile all your source code into build directory (HTML/CSS/JS) and that can be hosted on GitHub pages or any other server and work exactly how you want it to be.